# How to proxy wss websocket to a http forward proxy using Nginx?

Tags: nginx

I need to forward `wss` websocket traffic from a client to an internal forwarding proxy (that uses http and authentication) and then to an external server.  Is this possible using Nginx and if so, what does the config look like?

I do not control the second proxy so cannot make any changes there with respect to how it works.

So the flow looks like:

```
Client application (connects to `wss://example.com/api/path`) -> Nginx -> Proxy2 (uses http and basic auth) -> example.com
```

Is this possible with Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. This is taken from a working configuration....

```
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

                proxy_http_version      1.1;
                proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_ssl_name $host;
                proxy_pass https://internal.example.com/
```